# How do I "reopen" a git commit?

Tags: git, mercurial, rebase

(Note, I'm not looking for the answer `git rebase -i`)

In mercurial, I can "reopen" a commit by importing it into my patch queue:

```
hg qimport tip
```

The commit is "open" in the sense that it's just like before I had committed it, I can revert, do `hg diff`, `hg status`, etc. How do I do this in git?

(Everything I've found on the web suggests `git rebase -i` and then choose *edit*, but that's different, because the commit is not "open" in the same way.)

Comment: The other option is to leave the commit there, change some more things, and then use them to *amend* the commit (`git commit --amend`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to move your HEAD pointer up without making any changes to your working copy:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Reset moves the pointer, and the soft option specifies that it shouldn't change any of your files. The default is mixed, which will reset your index, and the hard option will actually remove the changes since that commit in your working copy.

HEAD is a "magic" git pointer that is always pointing to the current ref (i.e. the parent of your working copy). The caret (^) indicates the parent. You can use this repeatedly, e.g. HEAD^^ refers to the parent of the last commit.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Could you make a note that you lose the commit message, like @wulong did?

Comment: If you do actually want to use it repeatedly, `HEAD^^^^^` is the same as `HEAD~5`. (And more precisely, `HEAD` is a symbolic ref, pointing to the currently checked-out branch, which points to the currently checked-out commit, or straight to a commit if you're in detached HEAD state, with no branch checked out.)

Comment: @PaulBiggar: Avoiding losing the commit message is a great reason to amend instead of resetting. If you do reset, you can still indirectly recover the commit message, though. `HEAD@{1}` refers to the previously checked-out commit, which (if you haven't done anything else) will be the pre-reset commit. You can use `git commit -c HEAD@{1}` to use its commit message as a starting place. (If you have moved HEAD since then, you can use `git reflog` to find the commit farther back in the reflogs.)

Comment: @PaulBiggar It's inaccurate to say you lose the commit message when you do this since Git still retains it with that commit (which isn't lost until refs without any pointers are pruned). You can see it with `git reflog`. Like Jefromi mentioned, you can refer to another commit's message with the `-c` flag, but it's almost always easier just to copy-paste or rewrite it (in my experience, anyways).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't yet pushed to your remote repository, `git reset --soft HEAD^` will "reopen" your last commit at the expense of losing your commit message.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result using `git commit --amend`.

See [comparison chart](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table) between Hg & Git.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Chacon has (wonderfully) elaborated about the 'git reset' command: http://progit.org/2011/07/11/reset.html
Do not hesitate to have a look at it.

Comment: The link seems to be down, try this instead: https://scottchacon.com/2011/07/11/reset.html